# Ignorar arquivo com Python

Tags: python, io

Estou desenvolvendo um `client` que le arquivos `.JSON` e envia os mesmos para uma API. Os arquivos são depositados periodicamente em uma pasta. Porém, o que quero é que quando ocorra algum erro com o arquivo(arquivo sendo usado, arquivo com erro de sintaxe, etc) esse arquivo seja movido para outra pasta e o `client` ignore esse arquivo e continue lendo os outros. Como posso fazer?

Segue me código até o momento:

```
    for file in glob.glob(diretorioIn +'*.json'):

        print("Iniciando Leitura")

        try:

            payload = json.load(open(file))

            print(file)

            print(payload)
            print(file)

            headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}
            url = 'http://10.24.1.71/track/add'


            result = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

            print(result.text)              
            os.remove(file)

        except ValueError:
            print("Arquivo com erro: ")
            print(file)
            os.rename(file, diretorioErro)

        except PermissionError:
            print("Arquivo está sendo usado. Será movido para a pasta ERROR")
            print(file)
            os.rename(file, diretorioErro)



print("Nenhum arquivo encontrado. Reprocessando WebService")
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é marcar esses arquivos que estão sendo utilizados ou com erros, pois a partir do momento que eles estiverem em uso você não irá conseguirá move-los.
Coloque o caminho deles em um objeto list/dict e remova-os depois ou em um momento que garanta que eles estejam liberados.

Dica, faça a leitura do arquivo usando a declaração `with`:

```or-tag-here
with open(file_path) as df:
   data = json.load(df)
```

Assim você evita de deixá-lo aberto.